# cmd: Find updated folder and delete it using cmd

Tags: cmd

Using CMD line, in a given directory, I want to detect the most recently created/written folder and delete all the contents of that folder.

Any help/suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: just the contents or the subfolder as well ?

Comment: I wanna delete the files, subfolders and even the current folder too.
Thanq for the thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command prints all subdirectories in order of their last write/created time in reverse order (latest directories first):

```
DIR /A:D /O:-D /TW /B
```

To delete a directories' contents, a simple

```
DEL /S /Q "directory"
```

should be sufficient

If you want to process only the first result of the `DIR` command,  you can use a FOR loop in a  batch file, that leaves after the first iteration.
It should look something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM delete all contents from the sub directory most recently created or written to
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /A:D /O:-D /TW /B') DO (
   RD /S /Q %%A
   EXIT /B
)
```

Only works for the subdirectories of the current working directory, so use with care!
I guess for empty directories there will be some weird output, but I didn't test it.

**EDIT:**

Updated the batch file to remove the whole directory and its content using:

```
RD /S /Q "directory"
```

Comment: As you guessed, it is not working for empty directories. For non-empty directories, the code you have suggested is able to delete only the contents of the most recently created/edited folder....but, it is not the folder too. I wish to delete even the folder along with its contents. Thanks for your help Frank..